# python how to extract json out of javascript

Tags: python, json, parsing

What is a Pythonic way to extract the json out of a snippet of text, in this case JavaScript. 
It is a js function call with Json in the text, I want to extract the JSON out and parse it. I have been using regular expression but it has to be changed if any surrounding text is changed and have to mess around with escape characters like . each time. Is there a better way to do this?

`window._wq = window._wq || [];
  window._wq.push(function (W) {
    W.iframeInit({"assets":[{"type":"original","slug":"original","display_name":"Original file","width":1920,"height":1080,"size":491562565,"bitrate":2140,"public":true,"status":2,"progress":1.0,"url":"https://embed-ssl.wistia.com/deliveries/8137332c82d58a3207efafc.bin","created_at":1540249341},{"type":"iphone_video","slug":"mp4_h264_474k","display_name":"360p","container":"mp4","codec":"h264","width":640,"height":360,"ext":"mp4","size":109019112,"bitrate":474,"public":true,"status":2,"progress":1.0,"metadata":{},"url":"https://embed-ssl.wistia.com/deliveries/00a8759890e3d959ec72f101be.bin","created_at":1540249341,"segment_duration":3,"opt_vbitrate":1200}"flashPlayerUrl":"https://embed-ssl.wistia.com/flash/embed_player_v2.0.swf?2017-04-20","showAbout":true,"createdAt":1540249341,"firstEmbedForAccount":false,"firstShareForAccount":false,"useMediaDataHostLogic":true,"stats":{"loadCount":579,"playCount":232,"uniqueLoadCount":179,"uniquePlayCount":125,"averageEngagement":0.369201},"trackingTransmitInterval":59,"integrations":{"google_analytics":true},"hls_enabled":true,"embed_options":{"volumeControl":"true","fullscreenButton":"true","controlsVisibleOnLoad":"true","playerColor":"cccccc","bpbTime":"false","vulcan":"true","videoQuality":"","playsinline":true}}, {});
    window._wistiaHasInitialized = true;`

Comment: While [questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), I can say that you should pick a JavaScript parsing library in Python to parse the JavaScript code to get the node where the JSON is defined for that code, and then update your question to be specific about issues with usage of that library.

Comment: You know, that JSON you have begins with `[` but never gets closed so it's gonna produce an error in any language. Did you see that before?